# Unexpected None when changing values of a list copy via function

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, copy

I made the following two functions:

```
def make_great(magicians):
  for i in range(len(magicians)):
    magicians[i] += " the Great."

def show_magicians(magicians):
  for magician in magicians:
    print(magician)
```

I then pass the copy of a list of magicians to the make_great function, assign it to the copy variable, and pass that to the show_magicians function:

```
magicians = ['Peter', 'Hendrick', 'Charles', 'Ryan', 'Alex']

copy = make_great(magicians[:])
show_magicians(copy)
```

Which gives me TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

When I pass it the original list it works. However, I tried the following as well:

```
magicians = ['Peter', 'Hendrick', 'Charles', 'Ryan', 'Alex']

print(make_great(magicians))

make_great(magicians)
show_magicians(magicians)
```

Which gives the desired result, but the print function also returns a None object. I have two questions: 1) Why do I get the TypeError only with the list copy, and 2) Why does the make_great function return a None object in both cases (with the copy and the original list)?

Comment: Because `make_great` returns `None`, what did you *expect* it to return?

Comment: `Welcome to StackOverflow`. The question was well written. Several people did provide answers below. If an answer meets your needs, please accept it. If not post a comment under one or more of the answers. Whoever posted the answer will be notified of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `make_great()` function returns `None` because it has no `return` statement.

It uselessly updates its local copy of `magicians`, which is then lost as it goes out of scope when the function ends. You need to return the `magicians` list.

Comment: There is no local copy of `magicians`; the function updates the list it receives as an argument in place.

Comment: (It's the calling code that neglects to keep a copy of the list that *it* makes.)

Answer (score 0):

make_great(magicians) needed a return from the function.

"When I pass it the original list it works."
This was because magicians is mutable.
make_great(magicians) changed each of the elements in the list.

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for i in range(len(magicians)):
        magicians[i] += " the Great."
    return magicians

def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)


magicians = ['Peter', 'Hendrick', 'Charles', 'Ryan', 'Alex']

copy = magicians[:]
print(f'{copy=}') # Verify copy is not equal to None

show_magicians(make_great(copy))
print(f'{copy=}') # Demonstrate make_great mutated the list copy
```

Output

```
copy=['Peter', 'Hendrick', 'Charles', 'Ryan', 'Alex']
Peter the Great.
Hendrick the Great.
Charles the Great.
Ryan the Great.
Alex the Great.
copy=['Peter the Great.', 'Hendrick the Great.', 'Charles the Great.', 'Ryan the Great.', 'Alex the Great.']
```

Comment: You aren't calling `make_great` at all now, and passing the copy to the function that doesn't try to modify its argument in the first place.

Comment: **make_great** is called within **show_magicians(make_great(copy))**

Answer (score 0):

If `make_great` changes its argument in place, it's the *caller's* responsibility to maintain a reference to that list, not `make_great`'s responsibility to return a reference to it.

```
magicians = ['Peter', 'Hendrick', 'Charles', 'Ryan', 'Alex']
copy = magicians[:]
make_great(copy)

show_magicians(magicians)
```

If `make_great` will make a copy, it should leave the original list unchanged and return a reference to the modified copy.

```
def make_great(magicians):
    return [x + "the Great." for x in magicians]

copy = make_great(magicians)
show_magicians(copy)
```